# I was unable to login with this page and controller when i click on submit button after giving user credentials

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="false" sidebar="false" expires="0" cache="false" docType="html" controller="TargetX_Base.TX_CommunitiesBase" extensions="TX_CommunitiesLoginController">
    <style>
        .targetx-application-form-slide label span{
            color:#585e69 !important;
        }
    </style>
  <apex:composition template="{!defaultTemplate}">

    <apex:define name="content">

      <apex:form id="theForm" forceSSL="true">
        <ul class="targetx-application-form-slides">
          <li class="targetx-application-form-slide targetx-active">
            <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
            <h1 class="targetx-application-form-title">Login</h1>

            <label>
              <apex:inputText styleClass="targetx-input-text" required="true" id="email" value="{!email}" label="{!$Label.site.email}"/>
              <span>Email Address</span>
            </label>

            <label>
              <apex:inputSecret styleClass="targetx-input-text" id="password" value="{!password}"/>
              <span>Password</span>
            </label>


            <div class="targetx-application-form-slide-buttons">
              <apex:commandButton action="{!forwardToStartPage}" styleClass="targetx-button" value="{!$Label.site.submit}" id="submit" />

            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:define>

  </apex:composition>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
 //An apex page controller that exposes the site login functionality

 /*global with sharing class TX_CommunitiesLoginController {
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }

    public TX_CommunitiesLoginController () {}

    // Code we will invoke on page load.
    global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        if(startUrl == null) { startUrl = ''; }
        startUrl = Pattern.matches('(?i)tx_communitieslogin', startUrl) ? '' : startUrl;
        String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
        // return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType);
        return new PageReference(Site.getBaseUrl() + '/TX_SiteLogin?startURL=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(startUrl,'UTF-8'));
    }
}
*/
/**
 * An apex page controller that supports self registration of users in communities that allow self registration
 */

  global without sharing class TX_CommunitiesLoginController {

    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set;}

    public TX_CommunitiesLoginController(TargetX_Base.TX_CommunitiesBase controller) {}
    public TX_CommunitiesLoginController() {}

     global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        if(startUrl == null) { startUrl = ''; }
        startUrl = Pattern.matches('(?i)tx_communitieslogin', startUrl) ? '' : startUrl;
        String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
        return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType);
        return new PageReference(Site.getBaseUrl() + '/TX_SiteLogin?startURL=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(startUrl,'UTF-8'));
    }


    /*public pagereference loginuser(){
    return null;
    } */

    /**
    *
    private string randomNumber() {
        Integer i1 = Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
        Integer i2 = Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
        Integer i3 = Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
        return (String.valueOf(i1) + String.valueOf(i2) + String.valueOf(i3)).substring(0,3);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: HI Harish, please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Please use *words* to explain what your expected behavior is and what behavior you observe. Code dump questions and answers tend to be harshly received on this site.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm) suggests that your code will not log you in. All it will do is display a login form and then attempt to redirect the user back to the default login page. You are not actually authorizing the user. Also, if this page is set up as your default login page, you'll simply create a loop that your users cannot authenticate through.

Also note, you have 2 return statements 1 right after the other meaning your second return statement will **never** run.

I believe [this documentation](https://appirio.com/tech-blog/create-custom-salesforce-communities-login-landing-page) will help you get going in the right direciton if you want a 100% custom login page.

```
// Example from documentation provided.
/**
 * An apex page controller that exposes the site login functionality
 */
global with sharing class CustomLoginController {
    global String username{get;set;}
    global String password{get;set;}
    global CustomLoginController () {}
    global PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {
        return new PageReference( '/CustomLogin');
    }
    global PageReference login() {
        return Site.login(username, password, null);
    }
}
```